# Cannot access any svn file

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, permissions, svn

I put directory **svn** and **svn-auth** in **/var/www**
and already change owner and set permission with `chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn*` and `chmod 600 -R /var/www/svn*`

My configuration

**svn.mydomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName svn.mydomain.com
    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repositories"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/svn-auth/passwd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

some modification **httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8080
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
<Directory "/var/www">
```

nginx **svn.mydomain.com.conf**

```
server {
    server_name svn.mydomain.com;       
    location / {            
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }   
}
```

when try access svn.mydomain.com/project1 I cannot login and receive this **error_log**

```
[Fri Feb 01 04:36:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: Could not open password file: /var/www/svn-auth/passwd
[Fri Feb 01 04:36:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] access to /project1 failed, reason: verification of user id 'myuser' not configured
```

I try use `AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/svn-auth/passwd` then I can login but cannot access file with this **error_log**

```
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME/format': Permission denied
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #13]
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #13]
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME/format': Permission denied
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #13]
[Fri Feb 01 05:01:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #13]
```

Please help!!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are using RHEL/CentOS check if SELinux is go blame (/var/log/auditd.log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set +x permissions to directories as:

```
chmod 700 -R /var/www/svn*
```

Its because directories are data files that hold two pieces of information for each file within, the file's name and it's inode number.  Read permission is needed to access the names of files in a directory.  Execute permission is needed to access the inodes of files in a directory, if you already know the file's name.

Comment: thank you so much. Now I can fix permission deny problem. But new  obstacle occure can you help me how to access correct repository path here http://serverfault.com/questions/474579/cannot-access-svn-repository-in-correct-path Thank you so much.

Comment: 700 didn't work for me, but 777 did the trick.

Comment: Instead of explicitly defining 700, I think it would be a better option to use chmod +x -R /var/www/svn* because sometimes you might want to allow access to the group. On the other hand 777 would be too open.

Answer (score 2):

i solved the access problem giving 777 on www-data:www-data with commands chmod and own on var and var www and all that is below of it (-R),tested with web browser i can explore the repositorys

Comment: becouse my repository are under var/www/repos