# Cannot access svn repository in correct path

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, path

My repository directory is **/var/www/svn** and access file is  **/var/www/svn-auth** 
and I create repository project1 in svn directory

My configuration

**svn.mydomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName svn.mydomain.com
    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repositories"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/svn-auth/passwd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

some modification **httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8080
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
<Directory "/var/www">
```

nginx **svn.mydomain.com.conf**

```
server {
    server_name svn.mydomain.com;       
    location / {            
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }   
}
```

I can login but cannot access file It say file not found like this **error_log**

```
[Fri Feb 01 10:06:44 2013] [error] [client 115.87.26.145] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME/format': No such file or directory
[Fri Feb 01 10:06:44 2013] [error] [client 115.87.26.145] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 01 10:06:44 2013] [error] [client 115.87.26.145] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
[Fri Feb 01 10:06:44 2013] [error] [client 115.87.26.145] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
[Fri Feb 01 10:06:45 2013] [error] [client 115.87.26.145] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

then I try change `SVNPath /var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME` to `SVNPath /var/www/svn` and access svn.mydomain.com/project1 and **error_log** still show my wrong path

```
[Fri Feb 01 10:23:28 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/var/www/svn/format': No such file or directory
[Fri Feb 01 10:23:28 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 01 10:23:28 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
[Fri Feb 01 10:23:28 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
```

the right path should be `/var/www/svn/project1` 
 not `/var/www/svn/` , `/var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME`

I try use `SVNPath /var/www/svn/project1` and this work I **can access project1** but if I config like this I **can't access another project**

Please help!!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: does the svn `format` file exist? if yes, where is it located?

Comment: yes svn `format` file is already in `/var/www/svn/project1/format`

Comment: why do you have `SVNPath /var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME` instead of `/var/www/svn/project1/` ?

Comment: my repository should depend on url ex. svn.mydomain.com/project2

Comment: Have you made sure the filesystem permissions on everything under `/var/www/svn` is set in a way that makes it both readable and writeable by the Apache user?

Comment: I recursive set owner and chmod 611 to apache for svn and svn-auth before I change permission error_log is say permission deny. my early question here http://serverfault.com/questions/474500/cannot-access-any-svn-file Thank you.

Comment: As you can login, your configuration seems ok, but did you installed and enabled dav_mod_svn module, as it is required to access SVN filesystem over http.

Comment: I try use `SVNPath /var/www/svn/project1` and this work I can access project1 but if I config like this I can't access another project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, short blamestorming for your Apache's config

Your ServerName + Location + SVNPath means now:

For URL `http://svn.mydomain.com/` open repository, created at `/var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME`

If you haven't `/var/www/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME` directory **or** repository under this path, you'll get "Can't open file"+"Could not open the requested SVN filesystem" errors

If you want to have access to more than single repository under common base-path (`svn.mydomain.com/repository1`, `svn.mydomain.com/repository2`...) and place all repos as subdirs of `/var/www/svn/` you have to:

- Re-read SVN Book, [Basic Apache Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic) chapter
- Replace SVNPath by SVNParentPath and fix options accordingly
- (Optional) Add `SVNListParentPath on` - see "Listing repositories" from ["Repository browsing"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing) section